# Python-Celery Log

Tags: python-3.x, logging, celery, celery-task

I use flask, python 3.x and celery4 **(Total 8 workers)**

I want to make log files with **'RotatingFileHandler'** to split if file size is over.

It works fine at first log file. (It includes all workers log, PoolWorker-1 ~ PoolWorker-8)

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 sj sj   1048530  9월 18 10:01 celery_20170918.log (All worker's log)
```

But when file size is over, the worker write logs on seperated files.

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 sj sj    223125  9월 18 10:47 celery_20170918.log  (All worker's log except below 2, 5, 6))
-rw-rw-r-- 1 sj sj     43785  9월 18 10:47 celery_20170918.log.1 (only PoolWorker-2 log)
-rw-rw-r-- 1 sj sj     46095  9월 18 10:47 celery_20170918.log.2 (only PoolWorker-5 log)
-rw-rw-r-- 1 sj sj     45990  9월 18 10:47 celery_20170918.log.3 (only PoolWorker-6 log)
-rw-rw-r-- 1 sj sj   1048530  9월 18 10:01 celery_20170918.log.4 (Log file made at first is changed to this.)
```

I don't know what is the rule and they have any duplicated logs..!!!

My celery logger is as below.

**tasks.py**

```
logger = get_task_logger('tasks')
logger.setLevel("INFO")
filename = './log/celery/celery_task.log'
formatter = Formatter('%(levelname)s-%(asctime)s %(processName)s %(funcName)s():%(lineno)d %(message)s')
# FileSize rotating
fileMaxByte = 1024 * 1024 * 1  # 30MB
fileHandler = logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler(filename, maxBytes=fileMaxByte, backupCount=100)
fileHandler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(fileHandler)

@celery.task(...options...)
def test_call(self):
    logger.info("LOG TEST")
```

**test.py**

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_call.apply_async()
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RotatingFileHandler` don't maintain atomicity between multiprocess when do log file rollover.

In multi processes environment, process A see `maxBytes` reached on log file `c.log`, do a file rename to `c.log.1`, then write some log lines to newly created `c.log`.

But at the same time, another process B may still holding a handle of `c.log`, because [the way used to check file size](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/logging/handlers.py#L185), is based on the end offset of file handle, it also sees `maxBytes` reached, want to do file roll over on its own, because [the way used to roll over](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/logging/handlers.py#L93), is rename file on disk, this process try to rename `c.log` to `c.log.1`, but as `c.log.1` exists, renamed to `c.log.2`.

As there are other processes, `c.log.3` get created so on and so forth.

This issue is well addressed by using external logging mechanism, or you could wrap up your own atomic file rotating logging handler.

Comment: Thank you so much! Nice answer :) I will try to make my own rotation logger. Thanks!

Comment: Some examples of `external logging mechanism` would be a great addition to this answer.

Comment: @KBoehme it very much depends context, generally, you could use (r)syslogd/systemd.